Are "swim across the pool" and "swim widthwise" the same?
A river has 2 long ends and no short ends. So, when you swim across the river, you swim from 1 long side to the other long side.
On the contrary, a pool has 2 long ends + 2 short ends.
When you say "I swim across the pool", does it mean "I swim widthwise from one long side to the other long side"?.
Or does  "I swim across the pool" mean to swim either between 2 long sides or 2 short sides?

A river has two banks. We talk about 'swimming a length' of a pool when we swim from end to end, and 'swimming a width' from side to side. 'Swimming across' would probably be understood to mean widthwise.

Is that swimmers' jargon, Kate?    I've heard "I swam the length of the pool" but not the unit-of-measure version, "a length".


I swim across the pool.

doesn't have enough information.  We need to specify further:

I swim [lengthwise] across the pool.


I swim [widthwise] across the pool.

The first one means I swim from one short side to the other.
